# Copiar y Pegar en Celdas de DataGridView, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

Estoy intentando **copiar** el valor de una `celda` o varias y **pegarlo** a otra(s) `celda(s)`. Actualmente tengo este método básico que funciona.

```
myDataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText;
```

**Evento Datagridview KeyDown:**

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
{
   DataObject objeto_datos = myDataGrid.GetClipboardContent();
   Clipboard.SetDataObject(objeto_datos);
   e.Handled = true;
}
else 
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
{
    string texto_obtenido = Clipboard.GetText();
    string[] lineas = texto_obtenido.Split('\n');
    int fila = myDataGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int columna = myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    string[] celdas = lineas[0].Split('\t');
    int celdas_seleccionadas = celdas.Length;

    for (int indice = 0; indice < celdas_seleccionadas; indice++)
    {
         dgrid_hoja_horas[columna, fila].Value = celdas[indice];
         columna++;
    }
}
```

> Al ser un método muy básico, faltan realizar ciertos controles y validaciones:

- Necesito evitar **pegar datos en celdas `ReadOnly`**.
- **La `celda` solo debería aceptar el pegado de datos, si el dato copiado coincide con el formato del valor de la celda**. Formatos: (`Datetime` , `Decimal` , `String` ...). (De lo contrario mostrar alguna excepción).
- Utilizo este método en diferentes formularios por lo cual sería mas fácil **crear una función y no tener que duplicar el código**.

> **Nota:** se que este tema puede considerarse como amplio, pero aceptaría cualquier solución que puedan ofrecerme.

utilizo: *Visual Studio 2010* y *.NET Netframework 4*

**Editado:**

> Descargar codigo de Ejemplo: [CopiarPegarDatagridview.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tSnzicofB7VnYYMKQaq0Cf2Ax6ZwvMM8/view?usp=sharing) Enlace de Google Drive, **dentro hay un archivo TXT** leerlo por favor.

Comment: Si agregas un [mcve] seria una pregunta que se podria contestar.

Comment: @gbianchi , ¿De que parte necesitas que coloque un ejemplo verificable?, porque el código que he colocado es completamente funcional, es el que estoy usando actualmente, lo que sucede es que si copio un valor de una celda y lo pego en una celda `ReadOnly` este de todas forma pega el valor, y no controlo si el dato es string y el que requiere la `celda` es `Datetime` o `Decimal` etc...

Comment: mas que como ejemplo, para poder probar y ayudarte a encontrar una solucion. Si quisiera probar tu codigo, tendria que construir una app de cero.. y despues probar todos los casos... si tenes un ejemplo con los casos que fallan, es mas facil encontrar una solucion.

Comment: Ok comprendo, creare un pequeño proyecto para que se pueda probar el código, aunque en este momento no puedo, estoy un poco ocupado, pero mañana lo haré

Comment: @gbianchi He editado la publicación agregue esto: [Descargar codigo de Ejemplo: CopiarPegarDatagridview.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tSnzicofB7VnYYMKQaq0Cf2Ax6ZwvMM8/view?usp=sharing) Enlace de Google Drive, **dentro hay un archivo TXT** leerlo por favor.

Comment: He publicado como resolver mi pregunta, pero tengo un inconveniente si por ejemplo tengo 2 columnas `Decimal` `A` y `B` en las cuales debo validar que **el valor de B no debe ser menor al valor de A** o **el valor de A no debe ser Mayor que el valor de B**, esta validación la hago en el `Evento CellEndEdit` entonces al momento de pegar el dato no valida dicha información porque no se dispara este evento.

**¿Que debería hacer para resolverlo?.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo he solucionado por si otra persona necesita algo semejante aquí esta la respuesta:

> Encontré [este ejemplo de "codeproject"](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36850/DataGridView-Copy-and-Paste) del cual modifiqué lo que necesitaba para usarlo como quiero además de crear el evento para usarla en diferentes datagrids.

**Función Copiar:**

```
public void copiar_portapapeles(DataGridView datagrid)
{
     DataObject objeto_datos = datagrid.GetClipboardContent();
     Clipboard.SetDataObject(objeto_datos);
}
```

**Función Pegar:**

```
public void pegar_portapapeles(DataGridView datagrid)
{
      try
      {
           string texto_copiado = Clipboard.GetText();
           string[] lineas = texto_copiado.Split('\n');
           int error = 0;
           int fila = datagrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
           int columna = datagrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
           DataGridViewCell objeto_celda;

           foreach (string linea in lineas)
           {
               if (fila < datagrid.RowCount && linea.Length > 0)
               {
                   string[] celdas = linea.Split('\t');

                   for (int indice = 0; indice < celdas.GetLength(0); ++indice)
                   {
                       if (columna + indice < datagrid.ColumnCount)
                       {
                          objeto_celda = datagrid[columna + indice, fila];

                          //Mientras celda sea Diferente de ReadOnly
                          if (!objeto_celda.ReadOnly)
                          {
                              if (objeto_celda.Value.ToString() != celdas[indice])
                              {
                                  objeto_celda.Value = Convert.ChangeType(celdas[indice], objeto_celda.ValueType);
                              }
                          }
                          else
                          {
                             // solo intercepta un error si los datos que está pegando es en una celda de solo lectura.
                             error++;
                          }
                     }
                     else
                     { break; }
                }
                 fila++;
           }
           else
           { break; }

           if (error > 0)
              MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}  La celda no puede ser actualizada, debido a que la configuración de la columna es de solo lectura.", error),
                                        "ADVERTENCIA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException fexcepcion)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Los datos que pegó están en el formato incorrecto para la celda." + "\n\nDETALLES: \n\n" + fexcepcion.Message,
                                "ADVERTENCIA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }
        }
```

**Evento Datagridview KeyDown:**

```
public void datagrid_KeyDown(DataGridView datagrid, object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
     {
         copiar_portapapeles(datagrid);
         e.Handled = true;
     }
     else
     if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V) 
     {
         pegar_portapapeles(datagrid);
     }
 }
```

Sin embargo aun tengo una duda, si por ejemplo **tengo dos columnas `Decimal` A y B en las cuales debo validar que el valor de B no debe ser menor al valor de A o el valor de A no debe ser Mayor que el valor de B**, esta validación la hago en el **Evento** `CellEndEdit` entonces al momento de pegar el dato no valida dicha información porque no se dispara este evento.

**¿Que debería hacer para resolverlo?**.

> Si alguien lo hace con un **método distinto** por favor publicar su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de J. Rodríguez es buena y perfectamente funcional. Pero... tiene un "pero":

Al menos cuando se pegan celdas desde Excel al datagrid. En ese caso en la última celda de cada fila el valor pegado incluye un carácter '\r'. Esto puede pasar desapercibido en muchos casos. Pero a mi me suponía un problema. Afortunadamente la solución es sencilla. El codigo es todo identico excepto una unica linea que ha sido añadida. Eso es lo único que hay que hacer; añadir esa línea:

```
public void pegar_portapapeles(DataGridView datagrid)
{
  try
  {
       string texto_copiado = Clipboard.GetText();
       string[] lineas = texto_copiado.Split('\n');
       int error = 0;
       int fila = datagrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
       int columna = datagrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
       DataGridViewCell objeto_celda;

       foreach (string linea in lineas)
       {
           if (fila < datagrid.RowCount && linea.Length > 0)
           {
               string[] celdas = linea.Split('\t');

               for (int indice = 0; indice < celdas.GetLength(0); ++indice)
               {
                   if (columna + indice < datagrid.ColumnCount)
                   {
                      objeto_celda = datagrid[columna + indice, fila];

                      //Mientras celda sea Diferente de ReadOnly
                      if (!objeto_celda.ReadOnly)
                      {
                          if (objeto_celda.Value.ToString() != celdas[indice])
                          {
                              objeto_celda.Value = Convert.ChangeType(celdas[indice], objeto_celda.ValueType);
                              //A continuación la linea añadida para eliminar los '\r'. De paso, y por si acaso en algún contexto ocurre, tambien los: '\t' y '\n'
                                  objeto_celda.Value = objeto_celda.Value.ToString().Trim(new Char[] { '\t', '\n', '\r' });
                              // Fin linea añadida
                          }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                         // solo intercepta un error si los datos que está pegando es en una celda de solo lectura.
                         error++;
                      }
                 }
                 else
                 { break; }
            }
             fila++;
       }
       else
       { break; }

       if (error > 0)
          MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}  La celda no puede ser actualizada, debido a que la configuración de la columna es de solo lectura.", error),
                                    "ADVERTENCIA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException fexcepcion)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Los datos que pegó están en el formato incorrecto para la celda." + "\n\nDETALLES: \n\n" + fexcepcion.Message,
                            "ADVERTENCIA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo muchas gracias por compartir sus conocimientos , es algo bueno cuando uno practica ese habito , se muchas cosas de C# y C++ , sin embargo no lo se todo , el conocimiento es universal... estuve buscando en foros este tema y la verdad lei tu algoritmo , no asimile hasta endenderlo y practicarlo y le digo mi estamado , muchas gracias por su respuesta , me has ayudado

Answer (score 0):

antes que nada gracias por compartir su conocimiento con la comunidad, estoy tratando de usar este codigo pero en la funcion pegar_portapapeles me marca un error en la siguiente linea:

```
if (objeto_celda.Value.ToString() != celdas[indice])
```

error: object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.